# node.js project cannot find swagger-ui-express module

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, swagger, swagger-ui

In my app.js file, I'm calling to swagger-ui to be used as part of the project:

```
const swaggerUI = require("swagger-ui-express");
const YAML = require("yamljs");
const swaggerDocument = YAML.load("./swagger.yaml");

app.use(
  "/swagger",
  swaggerUI.serve,swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDocument)
);
```

when trying to run the project using docker compose im getting this error:

```
app_back_end  | [nodemon] 1.19.4
app_back_end  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
app_back_end  | [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
app_back_end  | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
app_back_end  | [nodemon] starting `node --inspect=0.0.0.0 ./bin/www`
app_back_end  | Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/0442f111-2e23-40db-a162-d67ed53acbc4
app_back_end  | For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
app_back_end  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
app_back_end  |   throw err;
app_back_end  |   ^
app_back_end  | 
app_back_end  | Error: Cannot find module 'swagger-ui-express'
app_back_end  | Require stack:
app_back_end  | - /app/app.js
app_back_end  | - /app/bin/www
app_back_end  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
app_back_end  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/app/node_modules/module-alias/index.js:49:29)
app_back_end  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
app_back_end  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
app_back_end  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
app_back_end  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:81:19)
app_back_end  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
app_back_end  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
app_back_end  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
app_back_end  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
app_back_end  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
app_back_end  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
app_back_end  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/www:7:11)
app_back_end  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
app_back_end  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
app_back_end  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
app_back_end  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
app_back_end  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
app_back_end  |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
app_back_end  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
app_back_end  |   requireStack: [ '/app/app.js', '/app/bin/www' ]
app_back_end  | }
app_back_end  | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Although the swagger-express-ui is downloaded using npm, im getting these errors, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: check you ```package.json```. It should have swagger-ui-express in your dependencies block

Comment: Did you rebuild the docker image after installing package?

Comment: yes I did build it, also, I don't have it in dependencies block

Comment: Please show your docker-compose file. Any volumes you have can cause the issue you're seeing.

Comment: `Dockerfile` would be helpful. Are you running `npm install` there?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by running

```
npm install
```

Seemed to fix the issue